# After issuing partial refund via PayPal RefundTransaction NVP API, IPN listener only shows payment status as "Refunded," not "Partially_Refunded"

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-nvp

When I issue a partial refund on my site using the `RefundTransaction` API operation, the refund is processed successfully. However, my IPN listener continually receives a payment status of just `Refunded` for this transaction. I am not sure why it isn't `Partially_Refunded`.

I have tested partial refunds with PayPal's IPN Simulator and my IPN listener returns `Partially_Refunded` every time during these tests.

Here's the beginning of my IPN listener file:

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    //mscampMail($my_email, 'MSCamp curl error', "Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // The IPN is verified, process it:
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process the notification

    require_once ('includes/mysql_connect.php');

    // Get payment status & parent_txn_id if refund
    $payment_status = escape_data($_POST['payment_status']);

    // Cart Items
    $num_cart_items = isset($_POST['num_cart_items']) ? $_POST['num_cart_items'] : '';

    $txn_id = escape_data($_POST['txn_id']);
    $user_id = escape_data($_POST['custom']);
    $order_total = escape_data($_POST['mc_gross']);
    $shipping_fee = escape_data($_POST['mc_handling']);
    $first_name = escape_data($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = escape_data($_POST['last_name']);

    // For guest orders, need name & address info for shipping
    $guest = $user_id == 0 ? 'guest' : '';
    $address_street = escape_data($_POST['address_street']);
    $address_city = escape_data($_POST['address_city']);
    $address_state = escape_data($_POST['address_state']);
    $address_zip = escape_data($_POST['address_zip']);
```

And the function that posts partial refund data to PayPal:

```
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_, $env) {
 global $live;
 // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.


 if("sandbox" === $env)
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$env.paypal.com/nvp";
 else
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";

 $version = urlencode('122');

 // Set the curl parameters.
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

 // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

 // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
 $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

 // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

 // Get response from the server.
 $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

 if(!$httpResponse) {
    exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
 }

 // Extract the response details.
 $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

 $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
 foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
     $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
     if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
        $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
     }
 }

 if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
    exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
 }

 return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}
```

And finally, code from the page that calls the function above when a user initiates the partial refund:

```
if ($live === false) $env = "sandbox";

// Set request-specific fields.
$item = urlencode($refund_detail['item']);
$amount = urlencode($refund_detail['cost']);
$inventory_num = urlencode($order_detail_id_for_refund);
$transactionID = urlencode($refund_detail['paypal_txn_id']);
$refundType = urlencode('Partial');     // or 'Partial'
$memo = urlencode("Refund of ".$refund_detail['item']);     // required if Partial.
$currencyID = urlencode('USD');         // or other currency ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr = "&L_INVOICEITEMNAME0=$item&L_SKU0=$inventory_num&TRANSACTIONID=$transactionID&REFUNDTYPE=$refundType&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID"; 

if(isset($memo)) {
    $nvpStr .= "&NOTE=$memo";
}

if(strcasecmp($refundType, 'Partial') == 0) {
    if(!isset($amount)) {
        exit('Partial Refund Amount is not specified.');
    } else {
        $nvpStr = $nvpStr."&AMT=$amount";
    }

    if(!isset($memo)) {
        exit('Partial Refund Memo is not specified.');
    }
}
```

Any advice or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as my client needs to be able to process partial refunds on the site. I've scoured Stackoverflow and Google for more information to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike,

The payment_status = Refunded txn will have a parent_txn_id field with the value of the transaction that was "partially" refunded.

Assuming you have stored that original payment in your database, the IPN listener can look up the original transaction and compare mc_gross from that record with the same field in the current IPN txn.  If different, it is "partial" refund.

Comment: Awesome suggestion, sir! Thank you so much! I'll be doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

In PayPal IPN, refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/. payment_status variable doesn't have 'Partially_refunded' value. For "Partially_refunded' transaction, the value is refunded.  . The IPN Simulator appears to have some inaccurate variable values.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Would you have any recommendations on how to able to process both partial refunds and full refunds from my site? I can either initiate a partial refund, update the database, then do nothing in the IPN listener if payment_status is "Refunded," or I can allow full refunds, using the IPN listener to receive refund info and then update the database accordingly. However, I currently can't do both.